# how to add active class in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

could you please tell me how to add active class in xslt using `call-template`?
here is my code
http://xsltransform.net/jxDigTt/1

**Expected output** :active class added in `A` because I pass 'A' as selected item

```
<ul>
      <li class="active">A</li>
      <li>B</li>
   </ul>
```

**Expected output** :active class added in `B` because I pass 'B' as selected item

```
<ul>
      <li >A</li>
      <li class="active">B</li>
   </ul>
```

full code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <hmtl>
        <head>
          <title>New Version!</title>
          <style>
              .active {
              color:red
              }
          </style>
        </head>
        <xsl:call-template name="submenu_navigation">
            <xsl:with-param name="selectedItem" select="'A'"/>               
            </xsl:call-template>
      </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="submenu_navigation">
        <xsl:param name="selectedItem"/>
        <xsl:value-of select='$selectedItem'/>
        <ul>
            <li>A</li>
             <li>B</li>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the XSLT. The xsltransform.net site is a great resource, but it is often unavailable, which would make this question very hard to answer, or be of benefit to others. Thank you.

Comment: it is fine now check http://xsltransform.net/jxDigTt/1

Comment: Yes. It is fine now, but it might become unavailable any time in the future, which means anyone checking this question would not have the full context. Your XSLT is not large, so it can be easily copied into the question. Thank you.

Comment: k I will do that

Comment: any update ? of this question

Comment: @TimC any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the `submenu_navigation` template like this:

```
<xsl:template name="submenu_navigation">
    <xsl:param name="selectedItem"/>
    <xsl:value-of select='$selectedItem'/>
    <ul>
        <li><xsl:if test="$selectedItem = 'A'">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">active</xsl:attribute></xsl:if>A</li>
        <li><xsl:if test="$selectedItem = 'B'">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">active</xsl:attribute></xsl:if>B</li>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>
```

The `<xsl:if>` makes the creation of the attribute conditional.